# "... that ... with ..." and "... which ... with ..."

Tags: prepositions, which-that

> 1. The fact that I communicated to Mona is irrelevant.
> 2. The fact that I communicated with Mona is irrelevant.

The only difference might seem to be the different prepositions, *with* and *to*.

Now, try replacing the *that* in each sentence by *which*. Do you agree that you can do it with 1) but not 2)? If so, what exactly is wrong with "The fact which I communicated with Mona is irrelevant"?

Comment: They mean different things, and the spelling is 'irrelevant'. Not sure what the question is, so voting to close.

Comment: I can put *which* in place of *that* in both sentences. I just have to add the requisite (IMO) commas. Why do you think you can't put *which* into the second sentence, Lewis?

Comment: Going by your question history, I have a feeling you are deliberately playing tricks on us, being well aware that *that* has two different functions (well, it has more, but only two are relevant here) — a pronoun and a conjunction —, but only in one of them is it replaceable with *which*. It's almost like you are creating a garden-path riddle on purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: *that* can be a conjunction or a relative pronoun; only when it is a relative pronoun can it be replaced with *which*.

Your first example could mean either of the following:

> a.) This fact, *which* I communicated to Mona, is irrelevant — **relative pronoun.**
>
> b.) The fact that I communicated *something* to Mona is irrelevant — **conjunction.**

If we read it as a), the word *that* in your example has a function **within** the predicate of the subordinate clause *that I communicated to Mona*: it is the object of *communicated*. What did I communicate? I communicated *the fact* ( = the antecedent of *that*).

If we read it as b), *that* just serves to introduce the content of the subordinate clause, but it does not itself have a function within the predicate of the clause: that's why it is called a conjunction.

In your second example, however, the preposition *with* makes it unlikely that an object is present: you would normally not say, *?I communicated this with Mona*. For that reason, we automatically read *that* as a conjunction here, not a relative pronoun; and only relative pronouns can be replaced with *which*.

Answer (score 2):

OP's first sentence is only "borderline" acceptable - [here's a chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=communicate%20to%20them,communicated%20to%20them&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing that *communicate **to** [someone]* has largely fallen into disuse over the past couple of centuries.

If we accept that "semi-archaic" construction, note that it *always* requires a "secondary object" (some information conveyed - here, *"the fact"*). It's largely stylistic choice whether this is further qualified as being *the information **that** was communicated*, or **which** *was communicated*.

The second sentence represents the normal phrasing when there *isn't* a secondary object (i.e. - it's irrelevant that any communication occurred at all, and the specific information isn't mentioned). But in this case, it has to be *the fact **that** [communication occurred]*. You can't use ***which*** there.

Thus, given that ***which*** can only be used where the intended meaning is that *some specific fact that was communicated* is irrelevant, most native speakers will force that interpretation and overlook the "unusual" phrasing in the first sentence. Personally, I wouldn't - I'd say...

> *The [specific] fact[s] which I **told** Mona is/are irrelevant*.

---

If you don't see a problem with *to*, consider *"He **communicated to me** that I should leave"*. I think most people would agree this is stilted/formal/archaic.