# "Which" or "what" or ... when referring to a main clause?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, relative-clauses, which-what

There are many answered questions that address the usage of "which" and "what" on this site—many of them marked as duplicates—and there is even a specific tag for this topic. But I could not find any answer for the following question:

**Should I use "which" or "what" or something else if I want to express**

> **A does B which/what causes C.**

Therein, "which/what" (the "which" or the "what") should not refer to B but to the act of A doing B (i.e. the predicate of the main clause).

For example see these alternatives:

> Bob writes on the blackboard **which** causes a screeching noise.
>   Bob writes on the blackboard **what** causes a screeching noise.

Please note: The noise is caused by the writing not by the blackboard.

Side question: **Would the use of a comma be appropriate here?**

There is a closely related question, "[Do we use “which” or “that” when referring to the preceding main clause as a whole?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79626/344946)", that aims on "which" versus "that" as the alternatives and is answered in favor of "which". But maybe "what" would be the better choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *which*. And you need a comma, otherwise the *which* may be interpreted as introducing a defining or restrictive relative clause with *blackboard* as its antecedent:

- Bob writes on the blackboard, which causes a screeching noise.

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p495) has a section in *relatives* with the title: *'which referring to a whole clause'*:

> *Which* can refer not only to a noun, but also to the whole of a previous clause. Note that *what* cannot be used in this way:
>
> He got married again a year later, **which** surprised everybody
> (NOT...,<strike>what surprised everybody</strike>).

A final point: we usually write *on* the blackboard, not *to* it.

Comment: Thank you @Shoe for the prompt and profound answer and the helpful hint on the right preposition when "writing _on_ the blackboard". I edited the question accordingly to avoid distractions.

Comment: @Jürgen. I assume your mother-tongue is German, which uses _was_ as the relative pronoun in such sentences, _was manchmal zu einer fehlerhaften Übersetzung verleitet!_

Comment: You are absolutely right: "What" resulted from an unconscious word by word translation from German. On the other hand, "writing on the blackboard" parallels exactly the German choice of the preposition: "Wir schreiben auf die Tafel". (However, we can also use "an (at) die Tafel".) So my abstraction kicked in at the wrong moment.

Comment: By the way, I like your apt and accurate [example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497535/which-or-what-or-when-referring-to-a-main-clause/497538#comment1200035_497538) of a German "was" clause very much.

Comment: @Jürgen. That's the problem with _language transfer_. English has a similar grammar to German, which facilitates learning it for German native speakers. But it also increases the likelihood of negative transfer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_transfer