# For which reason vs For that reason

Tags: which-that

I know that 'which' and 'that' open non-restrictive and restrictive clauses, respectively.
However, intuitively, it seems to me that they don't have the same functions in the phrases 'for which reason' and 'for that reason'.

Does 'for which reason' mean 'for one reason of an undefined number of reasons'.
and  'for that reason' mean 'for only this reason'.

What is the difference of 'for which' and 'for that' as used in the above examples?

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which -- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13269/correct-usage-of-which-that -- http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15212/14666 -- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67437/that-with-and-which-with

Comment: Care must be taken to distinguish different 'incarnations' of 'a word'. In _The shuttle bus, which is yellow, should be here shortly_ and _The shuttle bus that is yellow should be here shortly_, _which_ and _that_ are relative pronouns. Their antecedent is 'the shuttle bus'. In 'He lost in straight sets, which is what I predicted', the antecedent is the entire preceding independent clause. But in 'He had a side-strain, for which reason he lost in straight sets', _which_ (not _for which_) is a determiner, 'modifying' (addressing) _reason_.

Comment: Your premise is mistaken. *That* is used only with restrictive clauses, but *which* may be used with either restrictive or non-restrictive clauses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the comment. Great point about minding different 'incarnations'. To me, it seems that 'for that' could replace 'for which' in your example 'He had an injury, for which reason he lost.' Is there a difference between the two when they serve in that capacity?

Comment: You'd need a stronger interruption than is provided by a comma: 'He had a side-strain; for this / that reason he lost in straight sets.' A dash or separate sentences would also be correct here. In any case, most people would say: 'He had an injury - that's why he lost' or 'He had an injury, which is why he lost.'

Answer (score 1):

The phrases have the same meaning but they are used differently. You can use *which* but not *that* as a sentential relative clause:

> He eats too much, which is why he is unfit.
>
> *He eats too much, that is why he is unfit.

The second "sentence" above is a comma splice and to be avoided. You need to start a new sentence after *much*, or separate the clauses with a semi-colon. The same applies when *which/that* are replaced by *for which reason/for that reason*:

> He eats too much, for which reason he is unfit.
>
> *He eats too much, for that reason he is unfit.